# how many sha1 hashes per time on current hardware

Tags: hash, hardware, sha, gpu

How many sha1 hashes per second can current hardware (say a 500$ gpu) compute, when the input is 256 byte long? (or any other length).

The question behind is how long (or how costly) is it to mount a preimage attack against Cryptographic Generated Addresses (CGA, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_Generated_Address). Suppose a CGA is mainly build by the 59 leftmost bits of a sha1 hash, how long does it take to find another hash where the 59leftmost bits match the CGA. The complexity is O(2^59)

Another thread led me to this page http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html where the performance of different systems in computing hashes is measured. However im not 100% sure if I can read out my desired answer as the performance is measured in cycles/bytes and I assume that the hashes where generated on cpus.

Comment: pls feel free to comment/give feedback on the question itself. downvotes without further explanation are not helping me to improve

Comment: This isn't an InfoSec question, but a hardware performance question.

Comment: I updated the question to make the security part more clear. If it's still more of a hardware question I will move over. However in my opinion the topic is closely related to security, as hash function preimage resistance rely on hardware limitations right?

Comment: I understand that the question has security implications, but the heart of the question is hardware performance. The question is also impossible to answer in its current form. The GPU isn't the only factor: the OS, the rest of the computer hardware, and the program leveraging the GPU to compute hashes will also have an effect.